# How to implement authentication in ZF2

Tags: session, authentication, zend-framework2

There are a couple of examples online about how to write plugins implementing authentication in Zend Framework 2, but no clear information on how to use them in an application.  Does anyone have a working (complete) ZF2 app that implements a simple login screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

http://blog.evan.pro/getting-started-with-the-zf2-skeleton-and-zfcuser

it's a good example of how to get the standard skeleton application to work with the zfcUser module to provide exactly what you need.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20140215210722/http://blog.evan.pro/getting-started-with-the-zf2-skeleton-and-zfcuser

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful:  
  
http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/zend-framework-2-create-login-authentication-using-authenticationservice-with-rememberme/

Comment: please post the information as much as possible here in case the link goes dead.

Answer (score -1):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html

Start with that....i was sailing in the same boat as you were  when i started off.. I did not use zfcuser as i thought it was complicated for me to use in the small amount of time i had. But its the best way of doing it.

Check the wiki page for zfc user as well.

But you can do things really simple with zf2 authentication rather than writing your own module for it.

Comment: For newbies to Zend, it's not quite clear from the get-go how to tie in the text from Zend2's manual on authentication

Comment: I've gone with something custom because ZFCuser is too highly coupled to the views.. I needed a ZFCUser for just API's  what would you call something like that?

Comment: also please paste details in case that link goes dead